# Llave foranea sin llave primaria

Tags: sql-server-2017

Se que no es buena práctica y no debería hacerce, pero asi viene en el modelado y donde manda capitan no gobierna marinero, necesito saber si en SQL Server es posible hacer una llave foranea compuesta sin tener una llave primariaen la tabla, solo haciendo referencia a las llaves primarias de las demas tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer la tabla PRESCRIPTIONS, pero no tiene llave primaria y no entiendo como hacer la llave foranea compuesta.

Comment: Pues yo veo que se definio como llave primaria el campo `precription_id`. =|

Comment: Parece PK pero el signo es PF (Primaria y Foranea)

Answer (score 1):

`Necesito hacer la tabla PRESCRIPTIONS, pero no tiene llave primaria y no entiendo como hacer la llave foranea compuesta.`

```
Create Table customer
             (
             customer_id    Int Identity(1, 1) Primary Key
           , address_id     Int
           , customer_namer VarChar(100)
             );
Go

Create Table physicians
             (
             physician_id      Int Identity(1, 1) Primary Key
           , address_id        Int
           , physician_details VarChar(100)
             );
go
Create Table Ref_Payment_Methods
             (
             payment_method_code        Int Identity(1, 1) Primary Key
           , payment_method_Description VarChar(100)
             );
go
Create Table Ref_Prescription_Status
             (
             prescription_Status_code   Int Identity(1, 1) Primary key
           , payment_status_Description VarChar(100)
             );
go
-- Monton
Create Table Prescriptions
             (
             prescription_id          Int 
           , customer_id              Int foreign key references dbo.customer(customer_id)
           , physician_id             Int foreign key references dbo.physicians(physician_id)
           , prescription_Status_code Int foreign key references dbo.Ref_Prescription_Status(prescription_Status_code)
           , payment_method_code      Int foreign key references dbo.Ref_Payment_Methods(payment_method_code)
           , other_details            Int 
             );
```

O lo que es lo mismo, cada una de las columnas de Prescriptions es clave foránea de otra tabla. Por tanto las puedes directamente definir en la misma sentencia de creación. O individualmente (siguiente código) con un `Alter Table`, pero no es una llave foránea compuesta, puesto que las tablas a las que hace referencia, no tienen una clave primaria compuesta.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Prescriptions 
-- Monton
Create Table Prescriptions
             (
             prescription_id          Int 
           , customer_id              Int 
           , physician_id             Int 
           , prescription_Status_code Int 
           , payment_method_code      Int 
           , other_details            Int 
             );
Go
Alter table dbo.Prescriptions
Add Constraint fk_Prescription_Customers foreign key (customer_id) References dbo.Customer(customer_id);
go
Alter table dbo.Prescriptions
Add Constraint fk_Prescription_physicians foreign key (physician_id) References dbo.physicians(physician_id);
Go
Alter table dbo.Prescriptions
Add Constraint fk_Prescription_prSC foreign key (prescription_Status_code) References  dbo.Ref_Prescription_Status(prescription_Status_code);
go
Alter table dbo.Prescriptions
Add Constraint fk_Prescription_prMC foreign key (payment_method_code) References  dbo.Ref_Payment_Methods(payment_method_code);
```

Una foreign key puede ser compuesta, si la tabla a la que hace referencia, tiene una primary key formada por varias columnas, pero no es este el escenario, o al menos a mi no me lo parece.

Nota: Los tipos de datos escogidos, son por simpleza.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estas viendo mal el requerimiento la tabla si tiene un id único y las llaves foraneas son de las otras tablas no es compuesta es decir una llave foranea por cada tabla que tiene relación.

Tal como esta esta bien, Se te facilita hacer las tablas en el diagrama de BD de sql-server.

Comment: No tiene llave primaria, esta en rojo, pero dice FK, y hace relación a "Prescription_Items" la cual tiene dos campos en rojo que dicen PF(Primaria y Foranea)